# Can construction of temporaries be optimized out if the return value is not assigned?

Tags: c++, optimization

In the following example:

```
struct Foo
{
     Foo() { std::cout << "Foo constructor called\n"; }
};

Foo getFoo()
{
     return Foo();
}

int main()
{
     Foo foo = getFoo();
}
```

We can't rely on the constructor being called twice or once, because of copy elision:

> Copy elision is the only allowed form of optimization (until C++14)
> one of the two allowed forms of optimization, alongside allocation
> elision and extension, (since C++14) that can change the observable
> side-effects.

So the side_effects can't be relied on. If the return value is assigned, then we can be sure that the copy constructor will be called at least once. But how about if getFoo() is called (even accidentally) without assigning the return value? In this case can the compiler not construct any "Thing" at all? I have this case in my code:

```
template <typename T>
struct IntrusivePointer
{
    IntrusivePointer(T* ptr) : ptr(ptr) { if (ptr) ptr->increment_ref_count(); }
    T* ptr = nullptr;

    ~IntrusivePointer() { if (ptr) ptr->decrement_ref_count(); }
};


class Thing {
public:
    int ref_count = 0;
    void increment_ref_count() { ++ref_count; }
    void decrement_ref_count()
    {
        --ref_count;
        if (ref_count == 0)
        {
             recycle();
        }
    }

    void recycle();
};

struct Manager
{
    static inline std::vector<Thing*> availableThings;
    static inline int num_things_used = 0;

    /* IF FOR ANY REASON THIS FUNCTION IS CALLED AND THE RETURN IS NOT ASSIGNED THEN THIS SYSTEM MAY BREAK? */
    IntrusivePointer<Thing> getThing()
    {
        Thing* thing = availableThings.back();
        availableThings.pop_back();

        ++num_things_used;

        /* EVEN IF THE RETURN IS NOT ASSIGNED WHAT SHOULD HAPPEN IS THE CONSTRUCTION OF THE BELOW TEMPORARY. 
        - AS LONG AS "ANY" OBJECT IS CONSTRUCTED THEN IT WILL BE RECYCLED.
        - HOWEVER I'M NOT SURE IF THE OBJECT CONSTRUCTION CAN BE OPTIMISED OUT */
        return IntrusivePointer<Thing>(thing);
    }

    static void recycle(Thing* thing) { 
        availableThings.push_back(thing); 
        --num_things_used;
    }
};


inline void Thing::recycle()
{
    Manager::recycle(this);
}
```

If there's no assignment to the return value then technically there's no "copy elision", and any optimisation which eliminates the side effect from the IntrusivePointer construction would not be for the purpose of copy elision. It may be an optimisation to see that the return value is not used and to optimise it out, but if the construction has side effects and it doesn't fall under the conditions of "copy elision" or "allocation elision and extension" then it can't eliminate the side effects of the constructor.

Comment: `IntrusivePointer` is broken anyway, isn't it? Since it doesn't specify proper semantics for copy/move operations.

Comment: "_We can't rely on the constructor being called twice or once, because of copy elision:_": Aside from the obvious typos, the shown (default) constructor is always called exactly once. The only question prior to C++17 would be whether the implicit move constructor is called zero, one or two times. Since C++17 that is always zero.

Comment: @user17732522 That's not the full implementation, I didn't want to clutter the question with four different constructors and two operator=. I hope it gets the point across.

Comment: @Zebrafish In case you write `getFoo();` instead of `Foo foo = getFoo();` there can be 0 or 1 call to the move/copy ctor prior to C++17 while from C++17 onwards there will be exactly 0 call to the move/copy ctor.